# ASP.NET CreateUserWizard cancel button not visible in markup

Tags: asp.net, createuserwizard

The control buttons don't actually show up in the markup... I'm sure it's possible to do this, but I can't figure it out. I've tried adding a button, but then I get dupes. I suspect there's a way to set the command name and achieve this, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that when in design view, you can click the little arrow that appears on the top right of the control and convert to a template. This may also be .net version specific.

Comment: Maybe I picked the wrong template... I'll have another go at it and see what happens.